# Como utilizar LIKE em bindValue?

Tags: mysql, pdo

Como usar o operador `%`, para a `bindValue()`, na `query` abaixo:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM nfe WHERE (cliente LIKE :cliente OR :cliente_ IS NULL)';
```

Comment: Deu certo @luccasrodrigo?

Comment: Sim, perdão pela demora (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sua `SQL` seria:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM nfe WHERE (cliente LIKE :cliente OR cliente IS NULL)';
```

eu pude perceber tem um erro.

***Exemplos***:

#### Que comece com o termo informado:

```
$stmt->bindValue(':cliente', $variavel."%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

*ou*

```
$stmt->bindValue(':cliente', "$variavel%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

---

#### Que termine com termo informado:

```
$stmt->bindValue(':cliente', "%".$variavel, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

*ou*

```
$stmt->bindValue(':cliente', "%$variavel", PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

---

#### Em qualquer parte do termo informado:

```
$stmt->bindValue(':cliente', "%".$variavel."%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

*ou*

```
$stmt->bindValue(':cliente', "%$variavel%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

***Referencias:***

- [SQL Like](https://www.w3schools.com/SQl/sql_like.asp)
- [bindValue](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.bindvalue.php)

Comment: porque minha query seria `'SELECT * FROM nfe WHERE (cliente LIKE :cliente OR cliente IS NULL)';` ? @VirgilioNovic

Comment: se colocou um paramento `:cliente_`  isso é meio estranho isso não funciona do jeito que está, qual a finalidade disso?

Comment: @luccasrodrigo qual é o proposito do seu código, porque, como eu disse muitas vezes não é preciso outras vezes tem necessidade, só me responde no seu código atual ficou do jeito que queria?

Comment: Sim, só que agora ao me questionar, pude perceber que `cliente` e `cliente_` com as mesmas variáveis no bind acaba gerando redundância... certo?

Comment: Segundo o @jlHertel, essa redundância existe e é uma limitação do PDO, que não permite ter dois parâmetros com o mesmo nome.

Comment: @luccasrodrigo Ok